# Zoom in and out with mouse wheel on image with image map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagemap

I would like to add functionality to zoom in and out on an image with the mouse wheel.

The image also has image map coordinate.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or provide code so we can see what you have tried already.

Comment: i tried few online tutorial,In one case zoom in-out is working but the image map is not working. [link] (http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-for-Image-Zoom-In-Out-With-Mousewheel-imgViewer/)